# Adding a private field to a class in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have two relevant classes SpaceInvadersApp and HighScoreTableModel

I need to Add a new private field to the SpaceInvadersApp class of type HighScoreTableModel, and initialise this field at the beginning of the SpaceInvadersApp constructor.

This is my attempt I think I am not doing it correctly.

```
public class SpaceInvadersApp extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private final GamePanel game;

private HighScoreTableModel highScoreTableModel; // unsure about this

final private JMenuItem menuItemGamePause;

/**
 * Create new Space Invaders application.
 * @throws HeadlessException 
 */
public SpaceInvadersApp() throws HeadlessException {

    highScoreTableModel = new HighScoreTableModel("Name", "Score"); //unsure about this
```

Heres the relevent code from the HighScoreTableModel class

```
package spaceinvaders.highscores;

import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class HighScoreTableModel implements TableModel {


private List<String> col1StringList = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<Integer> col2IntegerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private String col1Name, col2Name;

private List<TableModelListener> listenerList = new ArrayList<TableModelListener>();

public HighScoreTableModel(String col1Name, String col2Name) {
    this.col1Name = col1Name;
    this.col2Name = col2Name;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The above code does not work. see //unsure about this

Comment: You aren't assigning values to all of the `final` fields, but what exactly *does not work* and how *does it not work*?

Comment: Are the two classes in the same package?

Comment: Eclipse says that value of the field  SpaceInvadersApp.highScoreTableModel is not used at line private HighScoreTableModel highScoreTableModel;

Comment: @Singular1ty SpaceInvadersApp is is the package spaceinvaders and HighScoreTabelModel is in the nested package highscores ie.spaceinvaders.highscores

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @Zhauo `Eclipse says that value of the field SpaceInvadersApp.highScoreTableModel is not used` - that's just a warning, but in the code you provided it is not being used. And if it's not being used, why add it at all?

Comment: @Eran Ok I Understand that I plan to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider looking the packages of this classes, the need to be at the same package or imported.

Another detail is your variable `menuItemGamePause`, it needs to be initialized since it is `final`.

```
final private JMenuItem menuItemGamePause = new JMenuItem();
```